# Where do I find the libvlc to include it on Ubuntu?

Tags: c, ubuntu, libvlc

I'm rouhgly new to Atom Editor, and I wanted to program my media player, based on `vlc/libvlc`, with it, but I can't include any files from `libvlc`. I downloaded it through the terminal with `sudo apt-get install libvlc-dev`, but now I can't find the files to include it.

Comment: Did you try `find /usr/include/ -name '*vlc*'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you installed using `apt-get`, you should be able to locate the location of all the files from a particular package using `apt-file`.

```
$ apt-file list libvlc-dev
```

If `apt-file` isn't already on your system, install it.

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

Comment: FYI, from what I understand `apt-file` will show where files *would* end up if you were to install the package. It's not showing you files necessarily already on your machine. It could list files in /usr/include/ but they may not be there on your machine if you haven't yet installed the library.